# How do I enable CI/CD for my aspnetcore 3.0 project (publish to IIS) using azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to build a 'build pipeline' for my aspnetcore 3.0 project.
I already have an IIS service running & added it to the deployment group.

So a bit about the app:
- ASP.NET Core 3.0.0-preview8
- Multiple web projects, one DAL project and a Core project
- One git repo for multiple website projects

And what do I need?
- Build the projects
- Test the projects
- Publish the projects to IIS 
- Make sure bind project to correct IIS binding (for example the api project should be bound to the API IIS website)

I've tried to use some templates but they didn't work.
I already tried doing it manually. 
I tried multiple configurations.

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '5739229b-68fa-4856-aa1c-1b52808407ae'
    noCache: true
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: 'teachers.dapperdino.co.uk'
    VirtualApplication: 'teachers.dapperdino.co.uk'
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip'
```

I expected the site to be published but it's not.
The output is:

```
##[section]Starting: DotNetCoreCLI
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.156.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
[command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.Ideas\DapperDino.Web.Ideas.csproj --configuration Release --output d:\a\1\a\DapperDino.Web.Ideas
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0-preview-19377-01+dd8019d9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 197.49 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj.
  Restore completed in 296.18 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Core\DapperDino.Core.csproj.
  Restore completed in 124.99 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Jobs\DapperDino.Jobs.csproj.
  Restore completed in 133.69 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.Ideas\DapperDino.Web.Ideas.csproj.
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Models\ApplicationUser.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(13,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(9,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityDbContext<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Models\ApplicationUser.cs(9,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(21,33): error CS0115: 'ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(11,76): error CS0311: The type 'DapperDino.DAL.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbContextOptions<TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DapperDino.DAL.ApplicationDbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(8,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.RoleManager\DapperDino.Web.RoleManager.csproj --configuration Release --output d:\a\1\a\DapperDino.Web.RoleManager
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0-preview-19377-01+dd8019d9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 26.28 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj.
  Restore completed in 28.19 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Core\DapperDino.Core.csproj.
  Restore completed in 304.79 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.RoleManager\DapperDino.Web.RoleManager.csproj.
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Models\ApplicationUser.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(9,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityDbContext<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(21,33): error CS0115: 'ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(11,76): error CS0311: The type 'DapperDino.DAL.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbContextOptions<TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DapperDino.DAL.ApplicationDbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(13,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Models\ApplicationUser.cs(9,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(8,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.Teacher\DapperDino.Web.Teacher.csproj --configuration Release --output d:\a\1\a\DapperDino.Web.Teacher
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0-preview-19377-01+dd8019d9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 24.95 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj.
  Restore completed in 30.07 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Core\DapperDino.Core.csproj.
  Restore completed in 2.06 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Jobs\DapperDino.Jobs.csproj.
  Restore completed in 414.17 ms for d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.Teacher\DapperDino.Web.Teacher.csproj.
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Models\ApplicationUser.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(9,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityDbContext<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(21,33): error CS0115: 'ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
ApplicationDbContext.cs(11,76): error CS0311: The type 'DapperDino.DAL.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbContextOptions<TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DapperDino.DAL.ApplicationDbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'. [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(13,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Models\ApplicationUser.cs(9,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
Roles.cs(8,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj]
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.Ideas\DapperDino.Web.Ideas.csproj,d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.RoleManager\DapperDino.Web.RoleManager.csproj,d:\a\1\s\DapperDino.Web.Teacher\DapperDino.Web.Teacher.csproj
##[section]Finishing: DotNetCoreCLI
```

csproj files:
DAL:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20181223043623_test.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20190103040438_orders.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20190602225729_test-migration.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20190602225729_test-migration.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20190622040133_product-download-link.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20190622040133_product-download-link.Designer.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Policies\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Core:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DSharpPlus" Version="3.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Jobs:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire" Version="1.7.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Ideas

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-DapperDino.Web.Ideas-D02C48DF-E6AA-418E-B7D1-0F9B0601AF20</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.Core\DapperDino.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.Jobs\DapperDino.Jobs.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

RoleManager:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-DapperDino.Web.RoleManager-DECFF1C6-FEE3-483B-9C80-C0D6BF8579BD</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.Core\DapperDino.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Student:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-DapperDino.Web.Student-BFD60CA3-10A3-4BAA-B5CE-9B284B72E3EC</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Teacher:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-DapperDino.Web.Teacher-CEB46A90-EAD8-4B53-974D-70B4CED675C7</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazor.Extensions.SignalR" Version="0.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DSharpPlus" Version="3.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Markdig" Version="0.17.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.Core\DapperDino.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.DAL\DapperDino.DAL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DapperDino.Jobs\DapperDino.Jobs.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me forgot to check in, switched package versions from preview 7 to 8....

Comment: I do still have  a problem though.
My site now successfully publishes to iis but somehow when the site is served it serves a 500 page, without any error information, tried to turn on logging but the error doesn't show up

Comment: That should be another question, One question one thread.  I suggest you open new ticket with more info about the new issue, there are a lot of communities here who are willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what happens is that your tasks do not keep their state for the subsequent steps, i.e. you are installing .NET Core 3 in one task, but it is lost when trying to run the next task, thus it cannot find any of the dependencies.

We can solve that using a job to contain all of the steps (tasks). If you add another job below this one, it starts out fresh again.

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Install, Test, Publish'
  timeoutInMinutes: 15
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'

  steps:
  # 1. Install .NET SDK 3.x
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET SDK 3.x'
    inputs:
      version: 3.x
      includePreviewVersions: true

  # 2. Restore
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: '5739229b-68fa-4856-aa1c-1b52808407ae'
      noCache: true

  # 3. Run Tests
  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

  # 4. Publish
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: True
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: True

  # 5. Deploy
  - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
    inputs:
      WebSiteName: 'teachers.dapperdino.co.uk'
      VirtualApplication: 'teachers.dapperdino.co.uk'
      Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip'`enter code here`
```

Note: You might also be able to run the test task the following way (you might have to modify it some):

```
  # 3. Run Tests
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Execute Tests'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration release'
```

Not saying it's the preferred way, but it might guide you in the right direction if VSTest@2 shouldn't be compatible for some reason.

Comment: I tried the example above, but this doesn't fix the problem.
What you told me made sense but for some reason the error is still the same.

Comment: Are you positive the `vmImage` is correct? Do you mind trying to replace it with `ubuntu-latest`?

Comment: The error might also be related to your .csproj-file and its dependencies come to think of it.

Comment: But if i build or run the project on my machine it gets all the packages, not at home rn but I'll post csproj files when I get back.

Comment: I added the csproj files

Comment: Well the vmimage should be correct, since it's just my windows vps running in azure.